# Get value from insert statement sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following insert statement for about 1000 rows and now I want to add one new column. The new column will have the value of version+ID in a `concat`.
How can I get the values from the `insert` statement and add it to the new column?
Will I have to make a dynamic SQL?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (Version,ID,Description) VALUES ('2002','1111','Desc')
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (Version,ID,Description) VALUES ('2002','1112','Desc')
```

Comment: from the `dbo`, I'm guessing this is mssql?

Comment: Are you asking how to add another column to these existing `INSERT` statements?  How to make an `UPDATE` statement after these are executed?  Something else?  Also, why do you need to duplicate data that already exists in the rows?

Comment: I will add a new column for each row which will hold version and ID in one column (concat). I don't want to write it for every row so my question is how to add this to my insert  statement in the easiest way?

Answer (score 6):

1. Run the Query to insert data
2. Modify the table by adding the new column
3. Run the following query

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.Table 
   SET NewColumn = Version + ID
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a computed column with Version + ID.  Depending on the usage you can make this a persisited computed column which will slow down writes but speed up reads.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to maintain scripts:

[image]

Find what: `(Description)\)([^\(]+)\('([^']+)',\s*'([^']+)',\s*(.+)\)` 
Replace with: `$1, NewColumn\)$2\('$3', '$4', $5, '$3-$4'\)`

Literally gets values from insert statement and stores to new column %)

Comment: Nice, where can I find more about regex for this?

Comment: I can not get the values

Comment: @Mcol, I did't understand about "values". Some regex dialect specifics for NPP search and replace dialog can be found in NPP help.